# Не работает вызов jquery методов после получения ajax ответа

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите пожалуйста в решении возникшей проблемы!

При выполнении ajax запроса произвожу некоторые действия "по защите от дурака", а именно:

```
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.calc").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}); // деактивирую нажатие по кнопке РАССЧИТАТЬ
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}); // деактивирую нажатие по кнопке ОТМЕНА
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-header > button.close").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}) // деактивирую нажатие по крестику вверху модального окна
```

;

[image]

Кнопки **ОТМЕНА** и **РАССЧИТАТЬ** и **крестик вверху** - заблокированы, т.е. назначен атрибут *disabled="disabled"* (это BootStrap).

После того, как пришел ответ от сервера я хочу произвести следующие действия:

```
    $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.calc").children().detach(); // удаляю кнопку Рассчитать
    $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").text("Закрыть"); // меняю название у кнопки ОТМЕНА на ЗАКРЫТЬ
    $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").attr({"disabled":""}); // снова активирую кнопку ЗАКРЫТЬ
$("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-header > button.close").attr({"disabled":"disabled"}) // снова активирую кнопку крестик
```

**Так вот!** Срабатывает только функция *.text("Закрыть")* а все остальное не происходит:

[image]

Вот сама процедура действия отправки данных и получение ответа в переменную **data**, процедура стандартная (блокировка кнопок происходит при нажатии на кнопку РАССЧИТАТЬ, пример кода не стал приводить т.к. он работает и наверное нету смысла показывать его):

```
//  CalculateDataCurrentMonth - Асинхронный запрос на сервер
    function CommitDataCurrentMonth()
    {               
        var sendMonth = $(".label.label-default.current-month").text();
        sendPost_CommitDataCurrentMonth(url, { sendMonth: sendMonth, fnCommitDataCurrentMonth: true });
    }

//  Подготовка POST-запроса
    function sendPost_CommitDataCurrentMonth(url, obj)
    {
    $.post(url,obj,onAjaxSuccess_CommitDataCurrentMonth);
    }

//  Отображение ответа сервера
    function onAjaxSuccess_CommitDataCurrentMonth(data)
    {
        $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-body > div.input-group.date").html(data);
        $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.calc").children().detach();
        $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-header > button.close").attr({"disabled":""});
        $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").text("Закрыть");
        $("#modal-afc-static > div > div > div.modal-footer > button.btn.btn-default.cancel").attr({"disabled":""});
    }
```

---

*Как всегда буду очень благодарен за помощь!*

Answer (score 1):

Друзья, сам разобрался, если кому-то интересно, проблема была в следующем:
*Надо было удалить атрибут **disabled** вместо того, чтобы устанавливать значение **""**.
Воспользовался методом **jQuery removeAttr**.*

Comment: а можно было еще проще - если до конца операции можно только смотреть на прогресс, - то тупо отключить все события для body до конца операции :)